# CentOS disable service (docker) before boot?

Tags: linux, centos, docker

[image: Centos stall screen]

I have a CentOS VM on VirtualBox that stalls at the above screen on boot. Previously, it was stalling on the gray bar screen and then I removed the quiet option in the kernel startup screen.

I think I will need to use grub to disable docker starting up automatically and that might fix it (I was having other issues with docker before rebooting). How might I do this? Do I need to use grub?

Answer (score 3):

docker is a system daemon and has nothing to do with grub. It's started after grub in the boot process. You need to disable it by running

```
chkconfig docker off
```

on CentOS6 or if you are running CentOS 7

```
systemctl disable docker
```

you might be able to login by switching to another virtual terminal (Ctrl + Alt + F2) to run these commands.
However looking at your screenshot docker does not seem to problem as it is starting with "OK".
Once you managed to disable automatic startup of docker at boot you can start the service manually by using these commands:

CentOS 6

```
service docker start
```

CentOS 7

```
systemctl start docker
```

and investigate further what is going wrong.